# IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

Tags: python

Estou com esse código em Python, mas aparece o seguinte erro:

> IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

Código:

```
import numpy as np
import math

A=11
T=(math.pi)/60
tf=15000
u=[]
x=[]
x=2*(np.ones((3,1)))

for i in range(1,tf):
    u = np.append(u,A*math.cos(i*T))
for k in range(3,tf):
    x = np.append(x,(2.1579*x[k]-1.3203*x[k-1]+0.16239*x[k-2]+0.0003416*u[k]+0.0019463*u[k-1])
print(x)
```

Comment: Ele está apresentando um erro de índice. o índice 3 está fora dos limites para o eixo 0 com tamanho 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O intervalo usado no seu laço `for k in range( 3, tf )` está extrapolando o limite da sua NumPy Array `x` já na  primeira iteração.

Sua NumPy Array foi inicializada com apenas 3 elementos:

```
x = 2 *(np.ones((3,1)))
```

A primeira iteração do seu `for` o índice `k` é `3` fazendo com que sua equação tente acessar um quarto elemento fora das fronteiras da sua array:

```
x[k]   # Mesmo que x[3]
```

A solução é fazer seu intervalo começar a partir do índice 2:

```
for k in range( 2, tf )
```

Segue solução com NumPy Arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import math

A = 11
T = (math.pi) / 60
tf = 15000

u = (np.zeros((tf,1)))
x = 2.0 * (np.ones((3,1)))

for i in range( 1, tf ):
    u[i] = A * math.cos(i * T)

for k in range( 2, tf ):
    x = np.append( x, 2.1579 * x[k] - 1.3203 * x[k-1] + 0.16239 * x[k-2] + 0.0003416 * u[k] + 0.0019463 * u[k-1] )

print(x)
```

Solução com listas `built-in`:

```
import math

A = 11
T = (math.pi) / 60
tf = 15000

x = [ 2.0 for i in range( 3 ) ]
u = [ A * math.cos(i * T) for i in range( 1, tf ) ]

for k in range( 2, tf ):
    x.append( 2.1579 * x[k] - 1.3203 * x[k-1] + 0.16239 * x[k-2] + 0.0003416 * u[k] + 0.0019463 * u[k-1] )

print(x)
```

**EDIT:**

Para gravar a lista `x` em um arquivo chamado `saida.txt` basta fazer algo como:

```
with open( 'saida.txt', 'w' ) as arq:
    for n in x:
        arq.write( str(n) + '\n' )
```

Comment: Uma outra dúvida, como faço para salvar esses dados 'x' em um arquivo .txt.

Comment: @CynthiaSilva: Segue edição com trecho de código capaz de gravar a lista de números em arquivo texto.